# c++ Multi-threading Argument Issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to pass a series of parameters into different c++ threads. The program runs fine when NumThreads == 1, however when NumThreads > 1,  the p parameter I pass to the function is incorrect within the thread. Am I missing something in the thread constructor and not passing p by value?

Where the threads are created:

```
int NumThreads = 2;
std::thread t[numSamplePoints];
std::mutex dataLock;

for( int i = 0 ; i < numSamplePoints ; i++)
{
  // Prevent more than NumThreads from running at once
  if( i > NumThreads && t[i-NumThreads].joinable() )
  {
    t[i - this->NumThreads].join();
  }

  // Set and Check Input Parameters
  double p[3];
  srcPoints->GetPoint(i , p);
  if( i < 3 )
  {
    cout<< "OUTTHREAD " << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] <<endl;
    cout<< "src: " << Id << " index: " << i <<endl;
  }

  t[i] = std::thread(&MyClass::MyFunction, this, &dataLock, i, Id, p);
}
```

And the member function being called:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(std::mutex *dataLock, int sampleIndex, int Id, double srcPoint[3])
{
  dataLock->lock();
  if( sampleIndex < 3)
  {
    cout<< "IN THREAD " << srcPoint[0] << " " << srcPoint[1] << " " << srcPoint[2] <<endl;
    cout<< "src: " << sourceId << " index: " << sampleIndex <<endl;
  }
  dataLock->unlock();
}
```

the console output from the first three threads:
{

```
OUTTHREAD 45.7694 1.06209 -60.9628
src: 0 index: 0
OUTTHREAD 48.6044 -5.40514 -54.7663
src: 108 index: 1
OUTTHREAD 52.505 9.00298 -47.0499
src: 216 index: 2

IN THREAD 52.505 9.00298 -47.0499
src: 0 index: 0
IN THREAD 52.505 9.00298 -47.0499
src: 108 index: 1
IN THREAD 52.505 9.00298 -47.0499
src: 216 index: 2
```

So ID and sample index are being passed correctly to the threads, but how is srcPoint the same for all three threads?!?

Comment: You're passing the same `p` array to every thread, and you may end up changing the values before the thread reads them.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Is `p` really the same? It is allocated anew for every iteration of the for-loop, or did I miss something? @JjBannister We don't know what is the `srcPoints` and we don't know what does the `GetPoints(int, double[])` function do. Maybe it's just correct behaviour.

Comment: I agree with @Mael it may be _correct behavior_ in how you implemented it; which may be _incorrect behavior_ in how you're expecting it to act. Race conditions are funny like that, as Matt points out.

Comment: @Mael, `p` is on the stack and is not allocated anew ever.  It actually goes *out of scope* at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop, so it really isn't valid to hand off a pointer to the thread which may use it after the iteration completes.  On the next iteration, the compiler will use the same memory for that iteration's `p`, although that behaviour is really undefined.  Note that variables declared after the for loop may also reuse the memory at `p`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans My bad, the going-out-of-scope part is what I wanted to say. Thanks for clarification. Does the standard say that the memory is to be reused across iterations?

Comment: @Mael.  No. It just is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behavior by passing a pointer to a local variable to your threads and allowing the variable to go out of scope before it's used.

C-style arrays are never passed by value.  A function declared to take an array type as an argument actually takes a pointer:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(std::mutex *dataLock, int sampleIndex, int Id, double srcPoint[3])
```

is equivalent to

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(std::mutex *dataLock, int sampleIndex, int Id, double* srcPoint)
```

In this case, your `p` array is local to your `for` loop scope, and it implicitly decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to your `thread` constructor.  As soon as each iteration of your loop completes, `p` goes out of scope and is destroyed, but your thread still has a pointer to the memory it used to inhabit.

The best option to fix this would be to replace `double p[3]` with `std::array<double, 3> p` in your loop and to make `MyClass::MyFunction` take a parameter `std::array<double, 3> srcPoint` instead of `double srcPoint[3]`.  Unlike raw C-style arrays, `std::array` can be passed by value, and implements the copy semantics you expect.

Comment: This was it. Thank you!!